# login to google with libcurl in C

Tags: c, authentication, libcurl

I try to login google using the libcurl library in C.
But google answers me : "Your browser's cookie functionality is turned off. Please turn it on."

Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

size_t get_buffer(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp); 

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  char *data="service=...&dsh=...&GALX=...&pstMsg=0&dnCon=&checkConnection=&Email=...&Passwd=...";   

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie"); 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, get_buffer);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);


    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: Offhand, having been to a Python scraping the web meetup, but not remembering everything, you might have to set additional fields in the "setopt" section. Sorry I cannot be of more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the web page twice to get the cookie. Please see:

> http://www.hackthissite.org/articles/read/1078

There's your answer @ "Retrieving a webpage (With cookies!):"